# How do I include superscripts in NSString?

Tags: nsstring

Is there any way I can include a superscript with NSString? For example, I want to write square feet, like this: foot<sup>2</sup>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this particular case, there is in fact a single Unicode character that represents a small "2" written above the line. It is U+00B2 (Superscript Two).

You should be able to do something like:

```
NSString *aString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:"foot\u00b2"];
```

Comment: Can we do that with string?? say for ex: TM